# How to find historical information on cake tickets that are not matching the current ticket numbering system?

Tags: cakephp, issue-tracking

This question target every cakephp user concerned by the missing old trac repository.

Tickets'numbers produced in 2008 have been remployed in 2011 in the new ticket numbering system for completly different tickets.

Is the old repository available somewhere ?

- https://trac.cakephp.org/ is not available anymore.
- http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/ tickets numbers does not match those of the old repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tickets, but probably not all, are available via the [Internet Archive](http://archive.org/web/web.php), see for example: http://web.archive.org/web/20070703220054/https://trac.cakephp.org/report